# Error al instalar paquete desde composer

Tags: php, composer

Quiero instalar un paquete utilizando composer y no se instala. Estoy utilizando una api de block.io

Cree mi archivo composer.json

```
{
  "require":{
    "block_io-php/block_io-php": "2.0.2",
    "bitwasp/bitcoin": "dev-minimal"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/doersf/bitcoin-php.git"
    }
  ]
}
```

Uso el comando `composer install` y tengo este error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires block_io-php/block_io-php 2.0.2 -> satisfiable by block_io-php/block_io-php[2.0.2].
- block_io-php/block_io-php 2.0.2 requires ext-gmp * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires bitwasp/bitcoin dev-minimal -> satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[dev-minimal].
- bitwasp/bitcoin dev-minimal requires ext-gmp * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gmp extension.
```

Espero me ayuden y gracias!

Comment: Ahí dice que antes de instalar esa librería debes instalar la extensión `ext-gmp` de php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas en windows tienes que ir a `C:\xampp\php` buscar `php.ini` y dentro buscar la linea que dice `;extension=gmp`. En esa linea debes quitar el punto y coma `;` para habilitar la extensión.

Guarda los cambios y en la terminal vuelve a utilizar el comando `composer install` y listo. Debe funcionar.